# append function apostrophe

Tags: javascript

I am appending the following:

```
$('#field').append("<input type='text' id='searchfield'  placeholder='Search...' autosave='save' results='5' onkeyup='onChange('searchfield','searchfield_right')' />")
```

it's appending, but the onChange function is not working due to  the apostrophe...

```
onkeyup="onChange('searchfield','searchfield_right')"
```

it should look like above with `"` and `'` for `'searchfield','searhfield_right'`

when appending you have to use `'` only 
so the `'searchfield','searhfield_right'` would be seen as `"searchfield","searchfield_right"`
which is not correct -

is there a different way to append the right apostrophe `'` for the function????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attribute value is delimited with `'` characters. So if you try to use a literal `'` inside the value, it will terminate the value instead of being part of it.

```
onkeyup='onChange('
```

Represent it with an entity (`&#39;`). Better yet (much better in fact), use [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript): attach event handlers with JavaScript, not HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Just escape them.

```
$('#field').append("<input type='text' id='searchfield'  onkeyup='onChange(\"searchfield\",\"searchfield_right\");' />");
```

However, I agree with David that you should use event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing string variables, just pass `this` and the `event`:

```
onkeyup="onChange(this, event)"
```

Then in your onChange function, you can use:

```
function onChange(element, event) {
   var id = element.id,

}
```

If however you are absolutely certain you want to pass strings, escape the quotations:

```
onkeyup="onChange(\"searchfield\",\"searchfield_right\")"
```

## ---> [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/KNRDQ/) <---